# TkInter ScrollBar does not work with ListBox

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Here is my code for a ListBox and ScrollBar.
The ScrollBar is showing at the right side of my frame but is disabled and not working when the items is ListBox exceeds its area:

```
frameLeft = Frame(self, relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 4)
frameLeft.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y, padx = 2, pady = 2)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frameLeft)
scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
lbModules = Listbox(frameLeft, relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 2.5, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
lbModules.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command = lbModules.yview)

for m in moduleList:
    lbModules.insert(END, Checkbutton(lbModules, text = m).pack(side = TOP, fill = X, padx = 2, pady = 2))
```

** moduleList is a list of strings
** Also if i add only the text to the ListBox, ScrollBar works but if i add the CheckButton, ScrollBar does not work.

Answer (score 3):

You can only insert strings to the listbox, and the scrollbar only affects things inserted into the listbox with the `.insert()` method. You simply cannot insert checkbuttons into a listbox.

In your code you're attempting to `pack` a checkbutton into a listbox, but that's not the same as `inserting` a checkbox in a listbox. While you can technically pack some other widget into a listbox, it won't be "in" the listbox and won't be scrollable.

In your specific case, the reason you see nothing -- not even the checkbox names -- is because you're inserting None for each checkbutton. In python, when you do `foo().bar()`, the end result is the result of the last command, `bar()`. So, when you do `Checkbutton(...).pack(...)`, the result is whatever `pack(...)` returns, which is always None. So, `lbModules.insert(Checkbutton(...).pack(...))` is the same as doing `lbModules.insert(None)`.

Comment: The CheckButton's added successfully. The only problem is if i add CheckButton, the ListBox's ScrollBar does not work. The ScrollBar works if i add String in the ListBox.

Comment: @Rosi_061: right. Like I said, the scrollbar only works for things _inserted_ into the listbox. You're not inserting anything, you're packing it, and that's different. You cannot _insert_ checkbuttons into a listbox. And if you can't insert it, it will not scroll.

Comment: Yes, so i used the lbModules.insert(...) but it did not work.

Comment: @Rosi_061: of course it didn't work. That's what I'm telling you -- it won't work. It's not designed to work the way you want it to. You cannot insert checkbuttons into a listbox. You can't. It's not designed to work that way.

Comment: Yes, i understood ... As i can not procedd with ListBox now, i am trying to build a TreeView with CheckButton. I can make the the tree from my xml file but can you tell me how i could be able to add CheckButton with each node of that tree?